# How to make items to resize automatically in windows forms when going on fullscreen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have many buttons in winform. it's look like buttons in calculator.
When I open full screen, buttons stays on top left side (same size they were before) and on the right side there is empty background of form.
How can I make them get bigger and stay centered relatively when I open winform on full screen?

Comment: Anchors and docking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 or less buttons per row/column, then you can use [anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=netframework-4.7.2).

However, if you have more than 2 buttons per row/column, you'll need to use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview) (granted you don't have an external controls library like DevExpress or Telerik) which you can then dock/anchor accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can dock your controls in the center. Try the following:

1) Select your controls through pressing **right cursor** of the mouse and hovering over your controls
2) Place your controls in the center
2) Go to **'Properties'** panel and find **'Anchor'** property
3) Deselect all the anchors (default anchors are top and right)

Try running and resizing your Windows Forms application.